# Prove that X can't possibly be a point on side BC that coincides with the midpoint or the other point of intersection of the nine-point circle.

Tags: geometry

In a triangle ABC Let a point  X be the point of tangency of the excircle opposite A with side BC. I am trying to prove the point X cannot cannot lie on the nine-point circle of triangle ABC. I proved that there could not be three intersections across side BC, but how can I prove that X can't possibly be a point on side BC that coincides with the midpoint or the other point of intersection of the nine-point circle?

Answer (score 0):

Let the triangle be isosceles and then use Feuerbach's Theorem and Feuerbach's Point to prove the conjecture.